# How to set buttons side by side in HTML

Tags: html, css

This is the CSS

```
.button2  {
    appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

this is the code i have try to set buttons side by side

```
<div class="container-button">
    <a href="#" class="button2">Order Now</a>
    <a href="#" class="button2">More Information</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show jsfiddle demo

Comment: They are side by side...

Comment: In this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xUbNm/ with your code they are side by side...

Comment: Its good in Jsfiddle. But when i am trying to execute in my project its not working

Comment: Than you have some options, give us a jsfiddle with your project code or try using inspect elements in chrome to see where it goes wrong.. Because there is nothing wrong with this code you gave us... it should be inside an other part of your code..

Comment: http://shajji.smartsocialapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/s4w.png
 this is the snap of the issue which i am trying

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons is already aligned side-by-side.
Check "display" property @

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/